# Como insertar un boton dentro de datatable Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql

tengo un código el cual realizo en JS tengo un Datatable que me lista datos traidos de una base de datos , le agregue 2 boton uno para aprobar y otro para eliminar , pero no se como darles funcionalidad , cree un jquery click function el cual me llama a las clases que les di a los botones , pero no funciona.
Mi gran duda es como poder darle funcionalidad a estos botones que están dentro de mi Datatable.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
console.log("ready");
cargarCampos(3);
obtenerReqAprobacion();

// TableManageDefault.init();
});

 function obtenerReqAprobacion()
{

let filas, cabecera;
let resultados=[];
let formData= new FormData();

filas="";
ajaxDinamicoForm("mesa_ayuda/obtenerReqAprobacion", formData, function(data)
{

    console.log(data);
    resultados=data.resultados;


        cabecera="<tr>";
        cabecera+="<th data-orderable='false'>N°</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Req</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Solicitante</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>VB de</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Descripcion Breve</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Responsable</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Observacion</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Comentario</th>";
        cabecera+="<th>Accion</th>";
        cabecera+="</tr>";


    $("#data-table-default").find("thead").html(cabecera);



        for(let i=0; i < data.resultados.length;i++)
        {

            filas+="<tr>";
            filas+="<td>"+(i+1)+"</td>";
            filas+="<td><a href='mesa_ayuda/detalle?req="+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' class='label label-inverse'>"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"</a> </td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].nCreador+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].nUsuario+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].DescripcionBreve+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>"+resultados[i].nResponsable+"</td>";
            filas+="<td>Ventaja: "+resultados[i].Ventaja+"<br> Desventaja: "+resultados[i].Desventaja+"</td>";
            filas+="<td><textarea id=tbComentario_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' name='tbComentario_"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"'  maxlength='255' rows='3'></textarea></td>";
            filas+="<td><button type='button' id='btnA"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' class='btn btn-primary envio aprob'> Aprobar </button> <button type='button' id='btnR"+resultados[i].cod_requerimiento+"' class='btn btn-danger envio neg'> Rechazar</button></td>";
            filas+="</tr>";

        }

    $("#data-table-default").find("tbody").html(filas);



    if ($('#data-table-default').length !== 0)
    {
        $('#data-table-default').DataTable(
        {


            responsive: true,
            "language":
            {
                "decimal":        "",
                "emptyTable":     "No hay solicitudes de aprobación disponibles.",
                "info":           "Mostrando _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registro(s)",
                "infoEmpty":      "Mostrarndo 0 a 0 de 0 registro(s)",
                "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
                "infoPostFix":    "",
                "thousands":      ",",
                "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                "processing":     "Procesando...",
                "search":         "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
                "paginate": {
                    "first":      "Primero",
                    "last":       "Último",
                    "next":       "Siguiente",
                    "previous":   "Anterior"
                },
                "aria": {
                    "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
                    "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                }
            }

        });

        $(".envio").click(function(){
            var n          = $(this).attr("id").lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
            var id_Req     = $(this).attr("id").substring(n,$(this).attr("id").length);       //Obtengo el ID
            var comentario = $("#tbComentario_" + id_Req);

            var aprobacion;

            if ($(this).hasClass('aprob') == true)
            { aprobacion = 1; }
            else
            { aprobacion = 0; }

            if ($.trim(comentario.val()) == "")
            { comentario.parent().addClass("error");
              $("#tbComentario_" + id_Req).focus();
              return false; }
            else
            {
              $.post("mesa_ayuda/actualizaResponsableAprob",{ req:id_Req ,
                                                             comentario:comentario.val() ,
                                                             aprobado:aprobacion }, 
             function(data) {

                { window.location = "baprobacion.asp?m=1" }
              });
            }
          });
    }

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque son elementos creados dinamicamente, es decir que no lo alcanzas normalmente ya que fueron insertados en un segundo momento en el DOM.

para llegar a esos botones tendrias que hacer lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#table").append("<tr><td><button id='enviar' type='button'>enviar</button></td></tr>");

      $("#table").on("click", "#enviar", function(){
          console.log("dato enviado");
      });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
</table>
```

para incorporarlo en tu codigo tendrias que hacer lo siguiente :

```
 $("#IdElementoPadre").on("click", "#IdTarget", function(){});
```

en cual el elemento padre tiene que ser un elemento que este presente en el DOM, osea ya definido en el HTML y el target seria el boton.

en caso que este metodo no te funcione otra alternativa, que personalmente no me gusta, pero tambien funciona es simplemente crear una funcion y ponerlo como `onclick` en el HTML :

```
<button type="buton" id="enviar" onclick="myFunction()">enviar</button>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, exitos

Comment: Gracias , me ha funcionado estoy capturando la clase, pero como capturo la id  realize esto con tu ejemplo y en un console log muestro lo que me traen los botones pero quiero capturar el id para darles funcionalidad         $("#data-table-default").on("click", ".envio", function(){
 
            
            var n          = $(this).attr("id").lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
            var id_Req     = $(this).attr("id").substring(n,$(this).attr("id").length);       //Obtengo el ID
            var comentario = $("#tbComentario_" + id_Req);

Comment: de nada un placer, y si, funciona exactamente igual sea con clase que con id y sirve para todos los elementos creados dinamicamente, no solo botones